# OrientJS: How to get standard JSON (serialized) from query

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I don't understand how to get standard JSON back from an orientjs query. I see people talking about "serializing" the result, but I don't understand why or how to do that. There is a `toJSON()` method, but i only see it being used with fetchplans etc...

I am trying to pipe a stream to a csv file and it isn't working properly because of the incorrect JSON format.

I would love an explanation of how and when to serialize. :-)

My Query:

```js
  return db.query(
    `SELECT 
      id,
      name,
      out('posted_to').name as page,
      out('posted_to').id as page_id,
      out('posted_to').out('is_language').name as language,
      out('posted_to').out('is_network').name as network 

    FROM post

    WHERE posted_at
      BETWEEN
        '${since}'
      AND
        '${until}'

      UNWIND 
        page,
        page_id,
        language,
        network
    `
```

My Result:

```js
[ { '@type': 'd',
    id: '207109605968597_1053732754639607',
    name: '10 maneiras pelas quais você está ferindo seus relacionamentos',
    page: 'Eu Amo o Meu Irmão',
    page_id: '207109605968597',
    language: 'portuguese',
    network: 'facebook',
    '@rid': { [String: '#-2:1'] cluster: -2, position: 1 },
    '@version': 0 },
  { '@type': 'd',
    id: '268487636604575_822548567865143',
    name: '10 maneiras pelas quais você está ferindo seus relacionamentos',
    page: 'Amo meus Filhos',
    page_id: '268487636604575',
    language: 'portuguese',
    network: 'facebook',
    '@rid': { [String: '#-2:3'] cluster: -2, position: 3 },
    '@version': 0 }]
```

Comment: kurtcorbett - Have you found an answer? If so, please don't forget to post it here; otherwise, if you haven't already done so, consider creating a ticket at https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues.  Meanwhile, here is a workaround using jsonlint, and assuming the explicit String representation of @rid is unnecessary: sed "s/\[String: '#[-0-9:]*']//" | jsonlint -Sf

Answer (score 0):

This is my dataset:

[image]

**Query:**

```
db.select('id','code').from('tablename').where({deleted:true}).all()
    .then(function (vertex) {
        console.log('Vertexes found: ');
        console.log(vertex);
});
```

**Output:**

```
Vertexes found:
[ { '@type': 'd',
    id: '6256650b-f5f2-4b55-ab79-489e8069b474',
    code: '4b7d99fa-16ed-4fdb-9baf-b33771c37cf4',
    '@rid': { [String: '#-2:0'] cluster: -2, position: 0 },
    '@version': 0 },
  { '@type': 'd',
    id: '2751c2a0-6b95-44c8-966a-4af7e240752b',
    code: '50356d95-7fe7-41b6-b7d9-53abb8ad3e6d',
    '@rid': { [String: '#-2:1'] cluster: -2, position: 1 },
    '@version': 0 } ]
```

If I add the instruction `JSON.stringify()`:

**Query:**

```
db.select('id','code').from('tablename').where({deleted:true}).all()
    .then(function (vertex) {
        console.log('Vertexes found: ');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(vertex));
});
```

**Output:**

```
Vertexes found:
[{"@type":"d","id":"6256650b-f5f2-4b55-ab79-489e8069b474","code":"4b7d99fa-16ed-
4fdb-9baf-b33771c37cf4","@rid":"#-2:0","@version":0},{"@type":"d","id":"2751c2a0
-6b95-44c8-966a-4af7e240752b","code":"50356d95-7fe7-41b6-b7d9-53abb8ad3e6d","@ri
d":"#-2:1","@version":0}]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @kurtcorbett, did you find it useful ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that worked for me. instead of using :

```
db.query()
```

i used http request in node to query on database. on [OrientDB Document](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/OrientDB-REST.html) also said you get only JSON format in result. this way if you query in database you will always get a valid JSON.

for making a http request i used request module.
this is a sample that worked for me :

```
var request =  require("request");
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer("root" + ":" + "root").toString("base64")

request(
        {
            url : encodeURI('http://localhost:2480/query/tech_graph/sql/'+queryInput+'/20'),
            headers : {
                "Authorization" : auth
            }
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(body);
            return body;
        }
    );
```